# How to change htdocs with Zend Framework

Tags: apache, zend-framework, htdocs

I just found and installed Zend Framework CE to test my web sites. I've used Apache before but this seems to be a great deal more gui and automated. My question is how do I change the Apache  C:/Program Files (x86))/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/  with Zend Framework? Is there a way to do it and have it update everywhere it needs to?

also, I'm planning on using Zend Framework to test my web applications on my computer and use the server live MySQL and then will upload the files manually, is this not the best way to handle this? (I just found out about this, what I've been looking for for a long time...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open httpd.conf located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\conf\
- Then change DocumentRoot "C:\you_doc_root" (about 1/3 the way down).
- As well, right 10-13 lines below that line change < Directory
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs" > to < Directory
  "C:\you_doc_root">
- then restart the server (right click on system tray icon).

Comment: Make sure that your new root folder exists because if it doesn't, Apache won't start.